# How to properly setup path in .bash_profile to run psql

Tags: macos, postgresql, bash

I'm trying to run pgSQL and have sourced seemingly every SO article to find a solution to no avail. I have my .bash_profile set up like so

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:'/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin'/psql -p5432:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

I got my path from running

```
locate psql
```

It returned this:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/share/doc/postgresql/html/app-psql.html
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/share/doc/postgresql/html/textsearch-psql.html
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/share/man/man1/psql.1
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/share/postgresql/psqlrc.sample
```

Here's a perplexing issue... if I run

```
echo $PATH
```

I get:

```
/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql:/usr/bin:/bin
```

My guess is this must be from having typed export however many times directly into the command line.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong here and how I can get it so I can run pgSQL from the command line?

Comment: `'/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin'/psql -p5432`: that part is wrong in a PATH. It should contain only directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an invalid entry for the `$PATH` variable: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin'/psql -p5432`

Most likely what you want is the following:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
alias psql="psql -p5432"
```

Keep in mind that aliasing `psql` in this way overrides any further use of `psql`, providing the `-p5432` argument (which may be undesireable/lead to confusing issues), so you may want to use a different name for the alias, like:

```
alias ppsql="psql -p5432"
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.